# Нужно асинхронно отправить, только одно значение input элемента, но на сервер отправляются все значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

После события blur,  *на сервер для валидации*,

нужно отправить  **только текущий элемент *input***.

Но на сервер, отправляются все элементы формы.

Как отправить на валидацию только текущий input ?
Может быть HTML форма так устроена, что любой  запрос отправляет всю форму?

Comment: submit Отправляет всю формую.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы отправить только текущий элемент, нужно слушать событие `blur` и в обработчике в переменной `this` будет хранится элемент. Ниже пример как вывести информацию о текущем элементе. По аналогии Вам нужно будет отправить данные на валидацию. Подробнее по событию `blur` можно почитать [здесь](https://api.jquery.com/blur/). А [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544554/get-the-clicked-object-that-triggered-jquery-blur-event/11544589#11544589) поднимался подобный вопрос, и есть ответы.

```js
$( "input" ).blur(function(e) {  
  $('#input-info').html($(this).attr('id') + ' value: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input id="in1">
<input id="in2">
</form>

<br>Current Input Info: <br>
<div id="input-info">

</div>
```